# Spring Security not allowing anonymous login

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Spring Web version : 2.6.4
Spring Security version : 2.6.4
Java : 1.8

I am trying to access a get api without Authorization and I am getting following error in the log

```
filter invocation [/error] denied for AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
```

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied

My Web security config

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        
        @Autowired
        private CORSFilter cORSFilter;
    
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().csrf().disable().anonymous().and()
                    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/*/**").permitAll().and().addFilterBefore(cORSFilter, WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.class);
        }
    }
```

My Rest Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/flow")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class FlowController {

    private final FlowService flowService;

    public FlowController(FlowService flowService) {
        this.flowService = flowService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/list/{clientRef}")
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    public List<FlowEntity> getFlows(@PathVariable String clientRef) {
        return flowService.getFlows(clientRef);
}
```

Comment: How is this question related to CORS? I'm dropping the [tag:cors] tag.

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace and second your pattern `/*/**` is imho wrong and should be either `/**` or better use `authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()` instead of what you have now.